# How to change the app registration in the bicep templates

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-bicep, teams-toolkit

The TeamsFx tabs example will provision a new azure "App Registration" automatically when you deploy an app however the code to provision this infrastructure does not appear anywhere in the bicep templates provided. Where does this get defined and how can app developer modified some of the details of the app registration.

For example we would like to add additional redirect url's on the app registration.

Answer (score 2):

For TeamsFx project, if you want to change AAD app registration, you can use aad.template.json file.

Here is the full document about how to customize AAD app using aad manifest file:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/aad-manifest-customization

For example, if you want to change AAD app names, you can follow the steps below:

1. Open `templates\appPackage\aad.template.json
2. Modify name property
   [image]
3. To update remote AAD app, from aad.template.json file context menu, click "Deploy Azure Active Directory app manifest"
   [image]

From your question, if you want to change redirect URL, you can modify
replyUrlsWithType property:

[image]

Comment: thanks @SLdragon looks liek this may have recently been added as my older template did not contain this. Upgraded and problem solved :)